# RabbitVCS issue on Mint 17 XFCE

Tags: linux-mint, xfce, thunar, version-control, ppa

Is there a working package of RabbitVCS for Linux Mint 17.3 XFCE Thunar FM 32 bit?
Following ubuntu section on rabbitvcs wiki, I've gone through the PPA repository option (rabbitvcs-thunar, rabbitvcs-cli, thunar-vcs-plugin). After reboot/log out&in, thunar becomes unresponsive, it opens two windows at a time and they are blank. As well the desktop turns blank, the icons disappear.

Then I tried Tarball option, when get to a step of thunar folder README to install some requirements, *thunarx-python* OK, *dbus-python* Not Present in apt-get repository so it's not installed by default, and **All Other RabbitVCS Requirements** whatever they are...

How to install dbus-python? Where to download it?
Would be possible to resolve the PPA option installation, peharps any missing steps?
Couldn't reach Clockwerx (developer?) ways of support anyway.